# Updating global variable on scroll event attached to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, events

I've got a situation where I want a variable to be updated when scrolling inside a `<div>`. There is a series of other things which will happen depending on this variable updating, so I don't want to wrap it inside the scroll event. Is there a way to avoid that?

Here is my JS:

```
var scrollEl = document.getElementById("scrollEl");

var scrollElWidth = scrollEl.offsetWidth;
var scrolled = 0;

var updater = function(updated) {
  scrolled = Math.round(updated);
  return scrolled;
}

scrollEl.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var percentage = 100 * scrollEl.scrollLeft / (scrollEl.scrollWidth - scrollElWidth);

  //This works
  console.log(updater(percentage));
});


//This doesn't
console.log('Updated scroll variable: ', scrolled);
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0u4fp0yv/

Comment: And my problem is ......

Comment: ..that the updated `scrolled` variable isn't reachable outside of the event listener.

Comment: may be using `Object.watch()` but not already impl for all browsers !